# Email Failed Message rejected for spam or virus content in Godaddy

Tags: email, virus

In Godaddy account email setup im facing an issue that whenever i send an email I receive the fail email, that messages contain spam or virus content with error but sometimes not always and also email is not in spam, all the email is send and receive but sometimes for receiptent i receive email. Can any body tell me please how to resolve the issue i talk to godaddy customer support but no anything occur.
Thanks best regards

Answer (score 1):

Let me first tell you how mail providers combat spam.
Typical spam filters use a point system to determine how reputable an email is (It contain the reputation of your domain and sending Ips). These points affect whether or not a mail is viewed as reputable enough to be delivered or not. Mail that meets this threshold for trust is typically delivered, and mail that does not is typically either marked as spam or treated with additional scrutiny.

There are several best practices and tips that you can follow to improve your reputation and deliverability.

Examples of Things that Build Trust (Must do)

```
Properly configured SPF (Sender Policy Framework) Record
DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail) Signed Email
Reputable SMTP Sender
Reverse DNS name matching name of sending Server
```

Examples of suspicious traits

```
No SPF Record, or sending from unlisted server
Coming from a SMTP Server with a history of bad behaviour
E-mail never received from recipients domain
```

Now, typically you need to build as much trust as possible in the eyes of the receiving mail server. Typically e-mail admins will go to great lengths to maintain deliverability.